# Accessing an ArrayList of an Abstract Superclass in a Subclass' method

Tags: java, inheritance, arraylist, abstract

This is just part of my code. I have this Abstract Superclass called Account, and I want to access the ArrayList in a Subclass's method:

```
public abstract class Account {
    private String accountNumber;
    private ArrayList<String> accountRecords;

    public Account() {
        super();
        accountRecords = new ArrayList<String>();
    }

    public String getAccountNumber() {
        return accountNumber;
    }

    public abstract void addTransaction(String transactionInfo);

}


public class SubAccount extends Account {

    public SubAccount() {
        super();
    }

    public void addTransaction(String transaction) {
        if (super.getAccountNumber() != null && 
            !super.getAccountNumber().isEmpty()) {

                accountRecords.add(transaction); //How can I access the 
                                                 ArrayList here?
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Write a getter for the arraylist in the super class and call super.getArrayList()

Answer (score 0):

Change the access of `accountRecords` to `protected`:

```
protected ArrayList<String> accountRecords;
```